# Appending to Dataframe inside Dataframe leads to nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For my master thesis in education I want to make a very simplified simulation of the internet. I am creating a quick and dirty python file to create a JSON file for the ASs.
For the creation I have a dataframe `nodes` which contains one column `neighbors` which itself is a dataframe. It contains an ipAddress, a latitude and a longitude. I want to append a row inside the inner dataframe at a given index.

I wrote a function:

```
def appendToNeighborDF(neighbor, ipAddress, latitude, longitude):
    neighborNew = neighbor.append({'ipAddress': ipAddress, 'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude}, ignore_index=True)
    return neighborNew
```

I use this function to append to neighbors column at a specific index via

```
nodes.at[index, 'neighbors'] = appendToNeighborDF(nodes.at[index, 'neighbors'], secondNode.ipAddress, secondNode.latitude, secondNode.longitude)
```

However, this did not work. When I printed `nodes.at[index, 'neighbors']` before appending it had the right format. When I printed `neighborNew` inside the function it was also exactly what I wanted. However, when I printed `nodes.at[index, 'neighbors']` after appending instead of the whole dataframe I only got `nan`. I am completely at loss, because the same method for appending seems to work completely fine a few cells before.

Comment: I corrected your function below. However, I am not sure why you need the nodes.at line as neighborNew already is appended

Comment: as far as I understand both append and concat do not operate inplace, but create a new df, hence I need to set the specific cell to the return value

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the data and the matching expected output

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `append` was replaced but `concat`.
Second, you need to use `pd.DataFrame` on your dict. Like this:

```
def appendToNeighborDF(neighbor, ipAddress, latitude, longitude):
    neighborNew = pd.concat([neighbor, pd.DataFrame({'ipAddress': ipAddress, 'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude})])
    return neighborNew
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it, but added brackets around the dictonary, because otherwise it would not run. However, unfortunately I still get that neighbors is nan at the given index after appending.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is your issue since you have not posted the whole code, but if the output looks good inside the function and is nan outside the function, is it possible you are forgetting to assign the function output to a variable when you call it? That would result in the behavior you describe.

The code below uses pd.concat() like [gtomer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10836309/gtomer) demonstrated, and sets ingore_index=True like you had done originally. By assigning the function output to neighborNew outside the function, I am able to print and view all the columns in the new dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

neighbor = pd.DataFrame({'neighbors': ['neighbor']}) # create initial DataFrame

def appendToNeighborDF(neighbor, ipAddress, latitude, longitude):
    new_columns = pd.DataFrame({'ipAddress': [ipAddress],
                        'latitude': [latitude],
                        'longitude': [longitude]})

    neighborNew = pd.concat([neighbor, new_columns], ignore_index=True)
    return neighborNew

# test with example values
# assign function output to neighborNew outside the function
neighborNew = appendToNeighborDF(neighbor, "192.168.1.1", 40.76, -73.98)

print(neighborNew)
```